# What tool(s) would be useful for trimming fishing line?

Tags: gear, fishing

After tying on a new fly when fly fishing, you need to trim the excess string.

As this needs to happen every time, what tool(s) would make the job easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something that works with a pinching motion and is on a lanyard for easy access.

Fingernail clippers will work, and there are also fishing specific clippers.

[image]

[Source](https://www.ebay.com/i/132357156121?chn=ps)

Knives would require two hands and scissors like on a multitool need to be opened with both. Clippers on the other hand are easy to work with just one hand.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use these.  Most people hat a set of these with them all the time  ;-)

[image]

[Source](https://depositphotos.com/19297835/stock-photo-man-clenches-or-grinds-his.html)

Comment: Does that actually work well? I would not imagine so, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: I used to do it when I was younger and for light line, (i.e. 4lb and under) it was acceptable.  Anything heavier, and it would just plain hurt.

Answer (score 0):

I like nail clippers for any mono line, and specialty scissors for braid.